# list of things that i dont know how to make

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

so i kinda new on web development scene and there is something i want to know how to make, here is the list that i want to make

- https://i.stack.imgur.com/ULW9g.png

what is that bar thing called? and how to make it stay on top when i scrolled

- https://i.stack.imgur.com/P9NKE.png

is this card or simple col that get styled using css?

sorry for the dumb question guys, i really kinda lost since i dont know how those thing called

Comment: first one is fixed navbar / sticky navbar, 
second one: looks like they are using card, grid, and some own css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Its called a navigation, or a navBar, and you position it absolute at 0,0 for it to stay up the top:

2) not sure what you are asking for your second question but to get it in that style. you can use CSS Grid, or FlexBox which are both native browser functionality.

Im happy to answer any further questions :)

welcome to the community

Comment: Happy to help :)

Answer (score 1):

The first one is a navbar or navigation bar. You can make it stick to the top by setting `position: fixed; top: 0; left:0; z-index:99;`

```css
nav {
  position: fixed;
  display: block;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.block {
  display: block;
  height: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<nav>
 Navbar
</nav>
<div class='block'>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
</div>
```

The second one you can achieve by nesting an element inst=ide another, applying a margin to the parent and border-radius to the child. It works with any layout style.

```css
div{
  border: solid 1px #ccc;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.container {
  padding: 20px;
}

.card {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.card-wide {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 150px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-right: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <h1>Content</h1>
  <div class='card'></div>
  <div class='card'></div>
  <div class='card'></div>
  <br />
  <div class='card-wide'></div>
  <div class='card-wide'></div>
  <div class='card-wide'></div>
  <div class='card-wide'></div>
</div>
```